# Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to scroll method overloads tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know what the keyboard shortcut to scroll a method's overloads that appears in the tooltip is? I presently have to resort to using the mouse to click the ^ and v labels in the tooltip, which isn't particularly effective.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The arrow keys work for me...

Comment: Gahh.. I was trying Ctrl+Up, Shift+Up, Alt+Up, PageUp.... never occured to me to just press Up. Thanks.

Comment: In VS 2019 this is not working for me. The intellisense recommendation box is there in addition to the overload tooltip and arrow keys are navigating the intellisense box. Edit: I think I found it. Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense > Automatically show completion list in arguments list (experimental).

Answer (score 66):

A little late but maybe somebody else needs it too:

1. Place the cursor after the first bracket
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Worked for VS 2019

Comment: Works in VS 2022 as well, kudos ;-)

Comment: This bring the overloads but doesn't answer how to scroll up or down between them.

Comment: The intellisense tooptip shows when `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Space` was pressed. The `Shift` + `Arrow Up/Down` scrolls up or down in VS 2022.

Answer (score 33):

> What's the command to bring up the tooltip? I know the shortcut in Eclipse (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) but that's Eclipse...
>
> In VS the tooltip shows when you type the first bracket but if I would like to see the different method overloads for a method that's been implemented already, how would I do that?

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to see the list of overloads and arguments.

See the [Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en) for more keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Note: in VS 2010, you have to have your cursor on the method arguments (not method name) when pressing ctrl+shift+space.

Comment: @KyleM - that was it!  I couldn't figure this out for the life of me, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes I have to hit escape to get rid of the intellisence popup before using the arrow keys to scroll through the overload list.

Answer (score 9):

**1. To Show Overloading Suggestions**

Place the cursor after the first bracket and press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `SPACE`  to bring it back.

Also, Erasing the opening bracket and writing it back can do the trick too.

**2. To Scroll through Overloading Suggestions/Options**

if your IntelliSense options are showing then press `ESC` which will hide it. Now, it's time to use the **`Up/Down`** arrow keys to see the charm.

if your IntelliSense is disabled, the **`Up/Down`** arrow keys will work directly.

Comment: This is the only complete answer for Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Pressing `ESC` and then using the up or down arrow keys did the trick. Thanks a lot! Using Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: Working the same way in Visual Studio Code 1.85. Most places just mention the arrow keys for navigating the overloads but not that you might have to *"hide" the IntelliSense suggestions first*. This part is probably depending on the version of VS/VSC and the IntelliSense settings.

Answer (score 4):

What's the command to bring up the tooltip? I know the shortcut in Eclipse (ctrl+space) but that's Eclipse...

In VS the tooltip shows when you type the first bracket but if I would like to see the different method overloads for a method that's been implemented aldready, how would I do that?

There's got to be an easier way than this:

- place the cursor just after the first bracket
- erase it
- re-type it (tada!)
- navigate the methods using up and down arrows
- when you're done, press ctrl+z to undo changes.

Answer (score 4):

**Ctrl + Shift + Space** in the **"()" method brackets** brings up the method overload context menu. The **UP and DOWN arrows** are used to navigate through and **ESC** (escape key) will close the tooltip.

The Visual Studio Keybindings definition is: Displays the name, number, and
type of parameters required for the specified method.

P.S. [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189) <- is useful - check it out.
I suggest looking for "VS-KB-Brochure-CSharp-Letter-HiRez.pdf" if you are looking for C#. Or look for the other "HiRez" versions of the other languages, a lot of the common things will overlap.

P.P.S. The following is a visual diagram poster which is an overall look and might be of interest to you on the same subject -> [Visual-Studio-2017-Poster](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017-poster/)

Answer (score 2):

Arrow keys are the short cut keys i suppose as they work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can type a comma after the last parameter of the function. That will bring up the intelisense menu [image: Visual Studio Intelisense]