# Navigate/scroll through overloads in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Ok, silly thing that has bothered me for a while...

(see image)
So, in Visual Studio, Id just hit the left parenthesis and can see that there are 2 overloads to the, in this case, Ok-function. If I want to see the other(s) I can reach over to my mouse and click the highlighted arrows. Works well. But if I want to use my keyboard, Visual studio thinks that I want to navigate in the dropdownlist, to fill the existing overload.

So, to keep it short. Can I scroll through the overloads with my keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. duplicate I guess... se the SO-post below(but **not** the accepted answer, so **Ctrl+shift+space works in 2019**)

[Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to scroll method overloads tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959024/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-scroll-method-overloads-tooltips/2279929)