# Why is intellisense in visual studio not showing method overloads any longer?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Does anyone know why my Visual Studio has suddenly stopped allowing me to select between different method overloads via intellisense? Instead it just seems to let me choose between a lot of different unrelated classes.

I can still select if I click the arrows though.

See example here:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959024/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-scroll-method-overloads-tooltips/2279929#comment113049810_959027?

Comment: Hi Anders, any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:) We are willing to help you further.

Comment: Thanks! ctrl-shift-space :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Tim said, to get what you want, you should first

invoke **Ctrl+Shirt+Space** and then use **Up** or **Down** of the Small keyboard to get the display of the overloading methods.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found it annoying to have both the popup methods suggestions & method overloads; I cannot use the up & down arrows to see the different overloads.

Solution: "Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> (pick your language) -> Intellisence", then uncheck "Automatically show completion list in argument lists".